# CallKit Interferes With WebRTC Video

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc, videochat, callkit

When I use CallKit to answer a WebRTC call, the video chat works most of the time. Once in a while the camera on my local iPhone isn't accessed correctly because of CallKit. When I remove CallKit, the video chat always works. Also if I set a delay for 1.5 second after I answer a CallKit call and then start the video chat, it seems to work well all of the time. What's the reason for this?

Answer (score 2):

Callkit is intended for Audio Call only, so callkit will activate AudioSession only.
Video will be activated only after you navigate to your application.

Try answering the call on phone lock screen, then you will get understood.

Test Facebook or any other popular app.

Comment: I do understand that CallKit activates AudioSession, but it can still be used for video calling with WebRTC in app. Right now my app works as follows. I pick up an Android phone. I send a video chat request to an iPhone. The iPhone gets a CallKit request. I accept the request and it starts a WebRTC video in app. This works perfectly, just not 100% of the time. If I add a 1.5 second delay after answering CallKit and starting the WebRTC video, it works all the time. My question is why do I need to wait 1.5 seconds? This solution seems like the wrong thing to do.

Comment: May be 1.5sec took for navigating to the app. If your phone is locked,  camera won't be captured.

Comment: This problem happens even when my app is open. It's almost like CallKit is using up resources that WebRTC needs. I use CXAnswerCallAction to detect when the user has picked up the phone. Without waiting 1.5 seconds to start the call, the video sometimes works. When it doesn't work, getUserMedia on the iPhone fails and shows a black screen instead of a video of the user.

Comment: Hmmm.. you are not reveling your observations in lock screen. Again am repinting after clicking on callkit answer button, there will be some transition time to navigate to your app. If your app is already in open/foreground, don't trigger callkit(atlest for video call)  directly show answer/reject inside your app.

Comment: The same thing happens whether in locked screen mode, foreground, and background. I prefer to use CallKit even when in foreground mode because it looks more like a call. There shouldn't be transition time if in foreground mode.

Comment: @DavidMarcus Hi David, maybe you could share how you implement what you mentioned above "I send a video chat request to an iPhone. The iPhone gets a CallKit request. I accept the request and it starts a WebRTC video in app." I am struggling to find how this can be done. I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @DavidShochet I used https://github.com/cordova-rtc/cordova-plugin-iosrtc

Comment: @DavidMarcus Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing your (re)connection logic in `providerDidReset(_ provider: CXProvider)`. You may also want to provide checks in this method to ensure you aren't resetting a successful connection.

Answer (score 0):

I am using WebRTC + CallKit in my App.
I started a call and when I press Lock / Power button then the CallKit call is getting disconnected and the My Voip call audio route changes to Receiver and remains.

Why locking the iPhone terminating the call.

Here is my Code.

```
    var callUUID: UUID?

extension AppDelegate {
    func initiateCallKitCall() {
        let config = CXProviderConfiguration(localizedName: "Huddl.ai")
        config.includesCallsInRecents = false;
        config.supportsVideo = true;
        config.maximumCallsPerCallGroup = 1
        provider = CXProvider(configuration: config)
        guard let provider = provider else { return }
        provider.setDelegate(self, queue: nil)
        callController = CXCallController()
        guard let callController = callController else { return }
        callUUID = UUID()
        let transaction = CXTransaction(action: CXStartCallAction(call: callUUID!, handle: CXHandle(type: .generic, value: "Huddl.ai")))
        callController.request(transaction, completion: { error in
            print("Error is : \(String(describing: error))")
        })

    }

    func endCallKitCall(userEnded: Bool) {
        self.userEnded = userEnded
        guard provider != nil else { return }
        guard let callController = callController else { return }
        if let uuid = callUUID {
            let endCallAction = CXEndCallAction(call: uuid)
            callController.request(
                CXTransaction(action: endCallAction),
                completion: { error in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("Error: \(error)")
                    } else {
                        print("Success")
                    }
                })
        }
    }

    func isCallGoing() -> Bool {
        let callController = CXCallController()
        if callController.callObserver.calls.count != 0 {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}

extension AppDelegate: CXProviderDelegate {

    func providerDidReset(_ provider: CXProvider) {
        print("-Provider-providerDidReset")
    }

    func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXAnswerCallAction) {
        print("-Provider-perform action: CXAnswerCallAction")
        action.fulfill()
    }

    func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXEndCallAction) {
        action.fulfill()
        print("-Provider: End Call")
    }

    func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXStartCallAction) {
        action.fulfill()

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(wallDeadline: DispatchWallTime.now() + 3) {
            provider.reportOutgoingCall(with: action.callUUID, startedConnectingAt: Date())
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(wallDeadline: DispatchWallTime.now() + 1.5) {
                provider.reportOutgoingCall(with: action.callUUID, connectedAt: Date())
            }
        }
    }

    func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXSetHeldCallAction) {
        action.fulfill()
    }

    func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, didActivate audioSession: AVAudioSession) {
        RTCAudioSession.sharedInstance().audioSessionDidActivate(audioSession)
        RTCAudioSession.sharedInstance().isAudioEnabled = true
    }

    func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, didDeactivate audioSession: AVAudioSession) {
        RTCAudioSession.sharedInstance().audioSessionDidDeactivate(audioSession)
        RTCAudioSession.sharedInstance().isAudioEnabled = false
    }
}
```